# Ionic tabbed menu

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I would like to build an Ionic app with [this functionality](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uacaps/ResourceRepo/master/PageMenu/PageMenuDemo.gif):

[image: Example]

The secret I'm trying to do is when I click on the last menu item and this item comes to the center of the menu, and the view comes to its regular functionality.

I've found [this slidebox](https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/tree/master/tabbedSlideBox) that works well, but it uses webkit and Android doesn't, so it doesn't work properly on Android.

I've been struggling with this for many hours. Do you have any idea about how to build one of these? I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good one.

Cheers to [JKnorr91](https://github.com/JKnorr91/ion-slide-box-tabs).

Comment: FYI it's always better to post actual code as these links can easily change